# Rendering of MUI TextField causes unwanted vertical scrolling

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a React App where the user can toggle between different views of the same data structure. When toggling from one view to another, the browser window sometimes automatically scrolls vertically. Instead I am expecting the window to not scroll when possible.

The CodeSandbox here reproduces the issue:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/magical-chebyshev-otlpu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

If you scroll down, then click on "CLICK TO SWITCH VIEW BELOW", you will notice that there's an automatic scroll to the top happening.

I suspect this is an issue with MUI TextField. If I change the MUI TextField to a div, the issue does not show up, so I don't think this is due to React.